# Custom Dialog DatePicker 24hourview error

Tags: android, datetimepicker

i have the following problem,i have a custom dialog, code is here:

```
 Button schedend = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonschede);
        schedend.Click += schedend_Click;



    }


    void schedend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DateTimePickerTemplate);
        dialog.SetTitle("Choose Date and Time");
        TimePicker tp = FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.timePicker1);
        tp.Is24HourView(true);
        dialog.Show();
    }
```

the `tp.Is24HourView(true);` gives me this error, No overload for method `Is24HourView`, takes 1 arguments. inside the dialog,i have a `datepicker` and a `timepicker`, here is the axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i set the timePicker to show a 24 hour format,it is currently showing the 12 hour format.
I have also tried  `tp.SetIs24HourView(true);`
but i get the following errors:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Widget.TimePicker.SetIs24HourView(Java.Lang.Boolean)' has some invalid arguments
and 
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'Java.Lang.Boolean'
```

I am a beginner at this, so i would really apreciate some help! Thx a lot!

Comment: Use `tp.setIs24HourView(Boolean.TRUE)`.

Comment: When i use tp.setIs24HourView(Boolean.TRUE),it sayz Bool does not contain a definition for .TRUE,and when i write Boolean. i get the following falsestring,parse,truestring,trystring.

Comment: I'll be removing my answer since its not helpful at all.

Comment: Found the answer, it should be written like this: tp.SetIs24HourView((Java.Lang.Boolean)(true)); and it will work.

Comment: Thx, it was quite wastefull,talking from a time perspective, but now it works so it dosent matter :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing  `tp.Is24HourView(true);` into  `tp.SetIs24HourView((Java.Lang.Boolean)(true));`

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explanations for your intension.